# Node.js request upload + Jersey server multipart resource => Gson stackoverflow

Tags: file-upload, jersey, request, gson, multipartform-data

I have a node.js client uploading a file using multipart form toward a Java based jersey server running on apache tomcat.

This is the node.js upload form:

```
var filePath = path.join(os.tmpDir(), filename);
var fstream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
file.pipe(fstream);

fstream.on('close', function() {
    var formData = {
        custom_file: {
            value:  fs.createReadStream(filePath),
            options: {
                filename: filename
            }
        }
    };

    request.post({
        url: apiBase + reqUrl,
        headers: options.headers,
        formData: formData
    }, function (err, resp, body) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send('Error');
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(body);
        }
    });
});
```

This is the jersey server multipart resource implementation:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response upload(@FormDataParam("custom_file") InputStream inputStream,
        @FormDataParam("custom_file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail)      {
            return null;
        }
```

I've also added jersey's multipart feature support in my web.xml:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
</init-param>
```

When I use this flow, my java server return the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [springDispatcher] in context with path [/app] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:95)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$WildcardTypeImpl.<init>($Gson$Types.java:549)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:108)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$ParameterizedTypeImpl.<init>($Gson$Types.java:453)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:99)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$WildcardTypeImpl.<init>($Gson$Types.java:542)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:108)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$WildcardTypeImpl.<init>($Gson$Types.java:549)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:108)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$WildcardTypeImpl.<init>($Gson$Types.java:542)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:108)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$WildcardTypeImpl.<init>($Gson$Types.java:549)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:108)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$WildcardTypeImpl.<init>($Gson$Types.java:542)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:108)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$WildcardTypeImpl.<init>($Gson$Types.java:549)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:108)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$WildcardTypeImpl.<init>($Gson$Types.java:542)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:108)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$WildcardTypeImpl.<init>($Gson$Types.java:549)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:108)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$WildcardTypeImpl.<init>($Gson$Types.java:542)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:108)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$WildcardTypeImpl.<init>($Gson$Types.java:549)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:108)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$WildcardTypeImpl.<init>($Gson$Types.java:542)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.canonicalize($Gson$Types.java:108)
```

What am I missing? I've followed both [request's step by step file upload using form](https://github.com/request/request#forms) as well as [mykong's jersey multipart support](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/).

Answer (score 1):

You should look for somewhere in your configuration where the GSON package is used, in my experience that package is not stable to say the least and slow.

Try and change it to one of the better ones out there "jackson" for example, it might solve your problem.